# passing values to another page in PHP

Tags: php

How do I get the `$row['getmeId']` value appear in `gotit.php` ?

Thanks

```
<div id='getme'><a href="gotit.php?id="<?php echo $row['getmeId']; ?>">GetMe</a></div>
```

Comment: You should read about `GET` parameters. See: http://php.net/get

Comment: I down voted for these reasons: What did you try? Did you get an error? Did you read (some) documentation etc etc etc. This is the very basics of the PHP language.

Comment: @stUrb Hi sorry i'm still learning. I have tried 'echo id;' but it just prints the value. so scrapped it. I see many are commenting here on $_GET. but I used echo $_POST['id']; but gave me a blank page. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendit.php

```
<a href="gotit.php?id=2345">Send Me</a>
```

gotit.php

```
<?php
print $_GET["id"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Escape the value to make it safe for HTML with `htmlspecialchars`
2. Put it **inside** the attribute value (remove your extra quote mark)
3. Read it with `$_GET['id']` in the next page

Such:

```
href="gotit.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['getmeId']); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access this value by

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

But make sure to sanitze the result as it might be evil.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters attached to the URL can be accessed by GET method, each parameter will be available as key for `$_GET` super-global array in PHP:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of $_GET['id'] to a new variable in gotit.php.

And for further info follow Patrick's advice.